# I am using an array to search values in a database(MS Access) but it is not working

Tags: php, sql

I want to use an array to search values in the MS Access Database. I tried to use prepare but i am having problem. I am new on Php. Please help thanks.

My code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=odbc_connect("Product","","");

if($con){
    echo "Connected";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}

foreach($_SESSION['NameOfItem'] as $key=>$value)
{
    $val = $value;
    
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM product where nameProduct = '.$val;
    
    $result = odbc_exec($con,$sql);
    
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {   
        echo "Name".$row['ID'];
        echo "Product".$row['nameProduct'];
        echo "Price".$row['price'];
    } 
}
?>
```

The error:

> `Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\product\phpCon.php on line 18`
>
> `Warning: odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\product\phpCon.php on line 20`
>
> `Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\product\phpCon.php on line 18`
>
> `Warning: odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\product\phpCon.php on line 20`

Comment: Welcome to SO. What problem do you have? Do you get an error? Which one? Or do you get an unexpected result? If so please write what you expected and what you go instead.

Comment: I am got the errors i posted above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your connection line should be :

$dbConn = odbc_connect($dns, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

Further, please have a look http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Comment: I used but it is not working. I was able to figure out a solution by using implode function in php. Now having difficulties with the Cache. Thanks again for replying :)